# In iOS Game Kit, is receivedata:fromPeer:inSession:context part of a delegate protocol?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates, gamekit

Often, the autocomplete in Xcode will autocomplete the method names for that class, and method names if the class in a delegate of some other object like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, 
                                              GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate>
```

But for the method of Game Kit, to be inside of `ViewController.m`:

```
- (void) receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer 
           inSession: (GKSession *)session context:(void *)context {
     // ...
}
```

It doesn't seem to be part of any delegate methods, either by Xcode's autocomplete or in any documentation?  If it is not part of a delegate, why is it different from the way all other delegate method works?

---

**Update: If I do a search for all the header files:**

```
grep -r receiveData /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
```

The only file that contains that line is:

> `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/Headers/GKSession.h:- (void)setDataReceiveHandler:(id)handler withContext:(void *)context;  // SEL = -receiveData:fromPeer:inSession:context:`

so it only shows up in a comment...

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for the `setDataReceiveHandler:withContext:` method in the `GKSession` class says:

> The handler must implement a method with the following signature:
>
> `- (void) receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession: (GKSession *)session context:(void *)context;`

This doesn't answer your question of why this method isn't implemented like a normal delegate method. I suppose this implementation provides more flexibility because you can have one object respond to `GKSession` delegate methods that manage the connection, while designating a different object to handle incoming data once the connection is made.

In any case, hopefully this answers the practical question of where this method is defined, which had me scratching my head for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's different because the API dates from an early version of Objective C (originally, protocols were less strongly-typed, and most callback methods were defined in this ad-hoc, non-compiler-checked fashion).

Most (almost all) of the core API's have been updated so that all protocols are explicit, all callbacks are typed - I guess they missed this one.